# MySQL Create Table with Unique Constraints

Tags: mysql, sql

I am just starting with SQL syntax, and am trying to create a table.

Here is my error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT uc_people_2nd UNIQUE (lastName,firstName), ) ENGINE = INNODB' at line 7

And here is my SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
`_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`lastName` TEXT NOT NULL,
`firstName` TEXT NOT NULL,
`JSON` TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(_id)
CONSTRAINT uc_people_2nd UNIQUE (lastName,firstName),
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

I tried this in NodeDB (which I am developing in), and then PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Fix the comma and make the names `varchar()`:

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
`_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`lastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`firstName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`JSON` TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(_id),
CONSTRAINT uc_people_2nd UNIQUE (lastName, firstName)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

This works on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00e5b8).

Note that you don't have to give a unique constraint a name.  You can also drop the `constraint` keyword, so the following works just fine:

```
UNIQUE (lastName, firstName)
```

EDIT:

The `text` data type is described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html) on the page with other "large-objects".  These are special types that are arbitrarily long (think megabytes).  They have limits when used in indexes.  In particular, they need a length prefix.  So, you cannot declare that a `text` column is unique.  Only that they are unique in the first N characters (up to about 1000).

For names, that is way overkill.  MySQL supports string types of various sorts.  The most useful is `varchar()`.  These are appropriate for a name field.  They can be used with indexes easily.  And MySQL supports a plethora of functions on them.

In other words, if you do not know what `text` is, you do not need it.  Learn about and use `varchar()` and `char()` (or `nvarchar()` and `nchar()` if you need national character set support).  Forget about `text`.  One day if you need it, you'll rediscover it.

Comment: what is the difference between varchar and text?

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered in a comment. Please read the chapter Data types, especially [String types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-types.html) of the manual.

Comment: @ArlenBeiler - as a side note, _names_ aren't really unique identifiers.  Think about `'John Smith'`.  I personally find this constraint suspicious.

Comment: True, in general. But in my case they are. If two people have the same name we add some other id to the combination, such as their dad's name. `'John (Dave) Smith'`. I'm building a Sunday School Attendance tracker, so we wanted some way to keep things separate.